# PostgreSQL search criteria must output missing row

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have two postgreSQL tables, namely: **employees** and **employee_cars**.
I need to output all employees that own a 'BMW', 'MERC' AND 'VW', BUT NOT an 'AUDI'.

I have tried below query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.employee_name, b.car_brand
FROM employees a
LEFT JOIN employee_cars b 
ON a.employee_id = b.employee_id
WHERE b.car_brand IN ('BMW','MERC','VW')
AND b.car_brand NOT LIKE 'AUDI';
```

OUTPUT below:

```
employee_name,car_brand
"Mary","BMW"
"Mary","MERC"
"Mary","VW"
"Paul","BMW"
"Paul","MERC"
"Paul","VW"
```

Problem is that each vehicle that an employee owns is a row in the employee_cars tables. So for example; I have 'Mary' which owns: 'BMW','MERC','VW','AUDI'.
I have 'Paul' which only owns: 'BMW','MERC','VW'. 
My query will display Both Mary and Paul, because they both own 'BMW','MERC','VW'.

I only want to see 'Paul' in my results, because he is missing the 'AUDI'.

Please note that I am not a DB expert, I will appreciate any help and assistance.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh, I see. By 'BMW', 'MERC' **AND** 'VW' you actually mean 'BMW', 'MERC' **OR** 'VW', right?

Comment: @Laurenz Albe , nope a little complicated:
  `'BMW', 'MERC' AND 'VW'` **AND NOT** `'AUDI'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I need to output all employees that own a 'BMW', 'MERC' AND 'VW', BUT NOT an 'AUDI'.* If you need employees to be distinct, not employee + car brand pairs, you can do this with aggregation:

```
SELECT   e.employee_name, string_agg(c.car_brand, ', ')
FROM     employees e
JOIN     employee_cars c ON e.employee_id = c.employee_id
GROUP BY e.employee_id
HAVING   COUNT(1) FILTER (WHERE c.car_brand IN ('BMW', 'MERC', 'VW')) = 3
AND      COUNT(1) FILTER (WHERE c.car_brand = 'AUDI') = 0
```

This will also filter out employees, who doesn't have either 'BMW', 'MERC' **or** 'VW' (like your question suggested).

http://rextester.com/MQL14836

**Edit**: for older PostgreSQL version use the `CASE` expression instead of `FILTER`ing:

```
SELECT   e.employee_name, string_agg(c.car_brand, ', ')
FROM     employees e
JOIN     employee_cars c ON e.employee_id = c.employee_id
GROUP BY e.employee_id
HAVING   COUNT(CASE WHEN c.car_brand IN ('BMW', 'MERC', 'VW') THEN 1 END) = 3
AND      COUNT(CASE WHEN c.car_brand = 'AUDI' THEN 1 END) = 0
```

http://rextester.com/KHMW56692

Comment: I believe this solution will work, However I am having a problem with FILTERing COUNT. I have PG version 9.2.

Comment: @JP_CNTLM_ADMIN you can use `COUNT(CASE ...)` then. I'll update my answer soon.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm... You sir, are a Legend!

Answer (score 1):

Combine this with a `not exists` condition:

```
SELECT distinct emp.employee_name, ec.car_brand
FROM employees emp
  JOIN employee_cars ec ON emp.employee_id = ec.employee_id
WHERE ec.car_brand IN ('BMW','MERC','VW')
  and not exists (select *
                  from employee_cars ec2
                  where ec2.car_brand = 'AUDI'
                    and ec2.employee_id = emp.employee_id);
```

Note that you do not need an outer join between employees and employee_cars

Comment: Hi @a_horse_with_no_name , thank you for your feedback. Your suggestion works great. Problem is with My and your `IN` statement, the query will return results even if an employee ONLY owns one vehicle, for example "John" Only owns a 'BMW'. I need the results to output only employees that own all 3 'BMW','MERC','VW' AND NOT an "AUDI".